# NEHotspotConfigurationManager unable use in M1 Mac

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

When I use NEHotspotConfigurationManager connect to a WiFi in iOS app, it can work fine.

However, I run this app in M1 Mac to connect to a WiFi always get the message:
`Domain=NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Code=8 "internal error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=internal error.}`

I choose run destination:
[My Mac(Designed for iPhone)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5rOg.png)

This is code I am use in my project:

```
NEHotspotConfiguration * hotspotConfig = [[NEHotspotConfiguration alloc] initWithSSID:_wifi_SSID passphrase:_wifi_PASSWORD isWEP:NO];

[[NEHotspotConfigurationManager sharedManager] applyConfiguration:hotspotConfig completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
     NSLog(@"=%@", error);
     if (!error) {     
        NSLog(@"Success to connect");            
     }else{
        NSLog(@"Fail to connect or already to connect");              
     }
}];
```

I don't understand if NEHotspotConfigurationManager support Mac WiFi setting.

Thanks in advance!